# how to connect CDash with gitlab internal postgres database

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce, cdash

I have an error `CDash cannot connect to the database` in the browser. I checked the configuration and what I think is that the CDash is looking for Postgres server on its own. However, my gitlab service is using its own builtin psql server located at `/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql`

I don't know how to update the CDash `config.php` to allow it to access the embedded Postgres database.

I am also not sure how to connect the user login from the terminal as we do in mysql i.e. `mysql -u cdash_user -p`

Here is part of the `config.local.php` file

```
// Hostname of the database server
$CDASH_DB_HOST = 'localhost';
// Login for database access
$CDASH_DB_LOGIN = 'cdash';
// Port for the database (leave empty to use default)
$CDASH_DB_PORT = '';
// Password for database access
$CDASH_DB_PASS = '*******';
// Name of the database
$CDASH_DB_NAME = 'cdash';
// Database type (empty means mysql)
$CDASH_DB_TYPE = 'pgsql';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following to make it work
Open the file

```
vim /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

Change the line

```
listen_addresses = ''
```

To

```
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1'
```

Save the changes and restart the gitlab

```
gitlab-ctl restart postgresql
```

Check the port on which the postgres is running

```
sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres
```

I had to do this because after gitlab update to version 12.2.0 the cdash stopped working.